# Как передать кодированный русский текст в URL?

Tags: jquery, base64, php, html, javascript

Добрый день, уважаемые!

Есть кодер ссылки на js

```
url = oneUrl + "?" + "l=" + btoa([secondUrl, cm_str, cen_str, metrika_str, body_str + cyrillic_text].join("/"));
```

И есть приемник на php куда направляет ссылка, который разбивает все это через  /

```
$decoded = base64_decode(htmlspecialchars($_GET['l']));
$decoded = str_replace(array('http://','https://'), '', $decoded);
$params = explode('/', $decoded);

$url = 'http://'.$params[0];
```

Я хочу добавить в js добавление еще одного параметра cyrillic_text русский текст в кодированном base64

Условно пусть **cyrillic_text** будет **$params[5]**
Хочу получить echo $params[5]; вывести кириллический текст

Урлы получаются такими, как их грамотно раскодить?

```
http://url.com/1/0/1/1/Мой текст с пробелами и !?.
```

base64 такой

```
aHR0cDovL3VybC5jb20vMS8wLzEvMS/QnNC+0Lkg0YLQtdC60YHRgiDRgSDQv9GA0L7QsdC10LvQsNC80Lgg0LggIQ==
```

Видимо из за / не работает как нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем b64 в URL? Не нужно изобретать велосипеды, есть стандарт, который описан в [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396) (начиная с раздела 2.4), и гуглить про "URI escape".